# white labelling existing asp.net web forms site

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms, white-labelling

I have a requirement to white label (specifically changing header logo/menu/font colors) our existing asp.net web forms site per each customer. Customer will be able to pick the colors they want for the site.

The site is a portal and consists of multiple web sites. I don't want to use themes or different master pages because we don't have the bandwidth for restructuring the app heavily. As far as I can see I have a few options. I want to know if there is more or someone knows any other better/best way to do this. The first two options may be similar but one could be better performance.

Have a dummy css class for all the "color changing" sections - say customColor.

Examples

```
<div class="menu customColor" />
<div class="header customColor" />
```

menu and header css classes contain all styles but the color.

1. Programmatically add color to this css class when the master page loads. Pseudo code : `Page.Header.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<style type=""text/css""> .customColor { color: blue }");`
2. Have a asp.net ashx handler return whiteLabel.css that contains `customColor { color:blue };` and add this css to the page dynamically.
3. It is not that many elements in every page that needs to change. You can have a function in each page that sets the appropriate colors from the database.

I assume my options pretty much are dynamically changing css or programmatically setting colors to individual elements.

Also I would think it may be better to do option#1 than #2 because does css get cached on #2? This will make it difficult for companies to change colors.

Comment: I would go with option #1. Make sure to properly encode any user supplied style information so as not to open yourself up to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A3-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS)).

Answer (score 0):

Does all your pages use a common MasterPage? 
If so, then I have once used setting a class for body or may be a div wrapper like:

```
<div class='<%= GetCustomClass() %>'>
    <div class="menu customColor" />
    <div class="header customColor" />
</div>
```

GetCustomClass is a static method that will return say class1 or class2 based on customer's selection.The css will look something like:

```
class1.customColor{color:blue;}
class2.customColor{color:red;}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's rule out option 3 also, it may fail to reskin the page if a javascript error occurs during the page load.

That leaves option 1, although you might want something a bit more readable:

```
<style>
    .menu.customColor { color: <%= menuColor %>; }
    .header.customColor { color: <%= headerColor %>; }
</style>
```